# C++ What happens when std::allocator goes out of scope?

Tags: c++, allocator

What happens when std::allocator goes out of scope? What happens to the resource it manages? If it is not deallocated beforehand, is it leaked?

Comment: an allocator merely implements a strategy to allocate memory, it does not own anything itself

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 not **every** allocator is like that. But `std::allocator` is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When `std::allocator` goes out of scope, nothing happens to the resource it manages.

Any resources allocated through `std::allocator::allocate` should be deallocated explicitly with a call to `std::allocator::deallocate`.

Any instance of `std::allocator` can be used for deallocation, and not necessarily the one used for allocation, because

> The default allocator is stateless, that is, all instances of the
>   given allocator are interchangeable, compare equal and can deallocate
>   memory allocated by any other instance of the same allocator type.

(https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator)

Comment: Ah! So, if we have two instances of an AllocatorAwareContainer container (a container that implements std::allocator), either instance of their allocators can allocate/deallocate memory for either container?

Comment: @sid for standard allocator - yes.